# Find element by Xpath. How to split the element I don't want inside the Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, list-comprehension

I try to scrape a website using Selenium.
I got a problem when I try to get the coins name. because there're 2 elements inside 'td'
How can I get rid of another element I don't want. or keep track to only its first element.
(I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911726/how-to-separate-output-of-xpath-statement) but I'm not sure if it answer my issue or not)

This is my whole code

```
#driver chrome def
website = 'https://www.bitkub.com/fee/cryptocurrency'
path = r"C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(website)

#giving variable
coin_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[2]//span")))]
chain_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[3]//div")))]
withdrawal_fees = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[4]//div")))]
#print(coin_name)
#print(chain_name)
#print(withdrawal_fees)


#for loop make list

for coin, chains, wdf in zip(coin_name, chain_name, withdrawal_fees):
    print("Coin name: {} Chain: {} Fee: {}".format(coin, chains, wdf))
```

The input of coin_name (which I mentioned that it got 2 elements)

```
['Civic(CVC)', '(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', '(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', '(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', '(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', '(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)', '(CRV)', .... ]
```

This is how element on the website look like
[image]

I wanted input to look like this so I can make dataframe out of it

```
['Civic(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)', .... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current output:

```
['Civic(CVC)', '(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', '(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', '(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', '(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', '(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)', '(CRV)', .... ]
```

You can skip every alternative element and create a new list using [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) as follows:

```
# coin_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[2]//span")))]
coin_name = ['Civic(CVC)', '(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', '(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', '(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', '(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', '(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)', '(CRV)']
res = [coin_name[i] for i in range(len(coin_name)) if i % 2 == 0]
print (res)
```

Console Output:

```
['Civic(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)']
```

Comment: Thank you ! haven't thought about using len. appreciated!

Comment: sorry, I still abit confused about this logic. why it has to be 'if I % 2 == 0' ? I can't understand how that work

Comment: You want the new list with elements with index `0`, `2`, `4`, etc where (index % 2) == 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
for name in coin_name:
    if name[0] == "(":
        coin_name.remove(name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! sadly there're names that like 'USDT' 'MATIC' 'GF' etc.

Comment: Thx. nice idea. however I'm using range(len) now and it worked. appreciated your contribution.